# How can I create a ViewResult Object?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

The SDK I am using is .net 6.0.201

There are some situations in the controller that need to return a 404 page.

Currently, I achieve it like this:

```
Response.StatusCode = 404;
///log something
return View("/Views/Others/Error.cshtml", 404);
```

However, I need to add the codes above to all the positions needed to return a 404 page. It is not well to manage the code. So, I am about to move all of them into an inject dependency class then reference it:

```
public ViewResult ErrorView(HttpResponse Response)
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            ///log something
            return new ViewResult("/Views/Others/Error.cshtml", 404);
        }
```

Now, VS reports an error that:

```
CS1729:'ViewResult' does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments.
```

What's wrong with my code? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to replace `return View("/Views/Others/Error.cshtml", 404)` that works and returns a view with something else?

Comment: @GSerg In spite of there are only several lines codes, it will occur a hundred times in my project. And also, it will be modified to return different view by the logic in the future, so I have to do this from now on.

Comment: I'm asking why you don't want to put the `return View("/Views/Others/Error.cshtml", 404)` inside `public ViewResult ErrorView`?

Comment: I have put it inside the public ViewResult ErrorView already. I don't why you said I don't want to put it.@GSerg

Comment: I said that because you put `return new ViewResult("/Views/Others/Error.cshtml", 404)` instead of `return View("/Views/Others/Error.cshtml", 404)`.

Comment: I have never noticed this. Is that almost the same, right?@GSerg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
public ViewResult ErrorView(HttpResponse Response)
{
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    var res = new ViewResult()
    {
        StatusCode = 404,
        ViewName = "/Views/Others/Error.cshtml"
    };
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to create a ViewResult object, you need to give it a string and a ViewDataDictionary object. The 404 is an integer and not a ViewDataDictionary.

Maybe try to modify the code like so, let me know if this works:

```cs
        {
            Response.StatusCode = 404;
            ///log something
            return new ViewResult(
               ViewName: "/Views/Others/Error.cshtml",
               ViewData: 
                   new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                                          new ModelStateDictionary())
                   {
                       Model = 404 // If the view is expecting an integer, 
                                   // if it's not, supply it with the correct model.
                   }
               });
        }
```

Comment: I am afraid it does not work. VS reports CS1739:The best overload for 'ViewResult' does not have a parameter named 'ViewName'